# Linux - Странные записи логов сервера (file does not exist)

Tags: сервер, centos

Добрый вечер!

Сегодня обнаружил следующие записи в логах сервера:

```
[Mon Nov 11 05:55:51 2013] [error] [client 183.60.244.44] File does not exist: /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/README, referer: http://www.baidu.com  [Mon Nov 11 05:55:52 2013] [error] [client 183.60.244.44] File does not exist: /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/Documentation.txt, referer: http://www.baidu.com
```

Во-первых, эти записи были в логах одного из сайтов. Следовательно, возникает вопрос, почему каталог /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/, а не /var/www/user/data/www/site.ru/? Также возникает похожий вопрос, как это кому-то удалось запросить директорию /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/, если она не является директорией сайта?Пробовал создать в директории сайта файл php, который запрашивал бы директорию /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/ (file_get_contents('/usr/share/phpMyAdmin/README')), при запросе файла в логах отражается ошибка

```
open_basedir restriction in effect...
```

Также пробовал просто зайти в phpMyAdmin, после чего смотрел в логи - там ничего.

Спасибо за внимание.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зато  `/usr/share/` является директорией сайта поумолчанию :) Вы конфиги посмотрите.Вот хороший ответ про то почему можно попасть `/usr/share`: [SO: why apache server redicect /doc to usr/share/doc][1], суть та же. Это (скорее всего) бот, который сканит сайты на предмет всяких открытых скриптов. Видимо файлы с именами README и Documentation скорее всего ищутся апачёв в этой директории.  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503814/why-apache-server-redicect-doc-to-usr-share-doc

Answer (score 2):

С phpmyAdmin все несколько по-другому чем с обычным сайтом.
1) это оболочка для управления базой данных MySQL;
2) устанавливается она действительно в /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/ и это ее рабочая папка;
3) что бы она была доступна с web-сайта делается ссылка на данную папку и рабочая папка phpmyadmin прописывается на Вашем вэб-сервере с параметром root сайта = /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/ ;
4) phpmyadmin запускается вместе с Вашим вэб-сервером. Если не используете - отключите. Достаточно переименовать папку, например в phpMyAdmin_  . Но в этом случе постоянно будут валиться ошибки.

Все правильно - все так и должно быть.
Другое дело, почему клиент запросил именно файл readme, который там вэб-сервер не нашел...
Зайти в phpmyadmin = www.yoursite.ru/phpmyadmin - если правильно настроен. Вход обычно по root-доступу к MySQLю.

Comment: оу, а про то, что оно туда ставится както забыл :) Всегда руками ставлю его, да еще и директорию переименовываю, чтобы всякие не копались.